# WCF Service Configuration Does Not Work in IIS

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS8, in Windows8, I use framework 4.5, I tried to add the endpoint according to the documentation however there is a part that is not clear to me; what do arguments mean:

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:808/Wcf_ProyectName/ClassServive.svc"/>
```

you can see details in the next video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6wZhuOdzGQ&feature=youtu.be

no matter how much change values ​​do not apply. It´s my configuration complete:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="Wcf_ProyectName.MiServiceName">
        <host>  
          <baseAddresses>  
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:808/Wcf_ProyectName/MiServiceName.svc"/>  
          </baseAddresses>  
        </host> 
        <endpoint address="MiServiceName" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf_ProyectName.IMiServiceName">          
        </endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AlmacenDB" connectionString="server=.\WIN8R2;database=AlmacenDB;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I found that when you publish the service to IIS, the host tag still exists in your configuration file. Only self hosted or hosted programs like windows service need to configure host. When you host the service in IIS, the base address of the service is composed of the port number deployed in IIS and the file name of the service.

[image]

This is the configuration file of WCF service deployed in IIS.

For more details on WCF deployment in IIS, please refer to the following link:

[WCF / EF / SQL Server / VS2017 / C# : multi-tier application gets error when deployed to local IIS 10.0 as hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014065/wcf-ef-sql-server-vs2017-c-sharp-multi-tier-application-gets-error-whe/62016193#62016193)

Comment: OK,thanks but I don't know why when I try to perform an operation on the database, it thrwon an error 'An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details' it problem was also not resolved in the post link mentionated

Comment: In the end I chose to change my connection string, change the Application Pool by User Identity on my pc